# laravel Class 'Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error, package, shopping-cart

Getting above error when i uploaded code to live server in my local pc all working perfect

Following things i have double check all settings are complete

- Added providers in app file Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider::class,
- Added alias in app file 'Cart' => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::class,
- composer.json already have "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",
- uploaded "gloudemans" folder in vendor folder
- Added cart.php in config folder
- Even i am not able clear cache due to this error

Comment: composer dump-autoload? But really you should not upload anything to vendor folder manually, run composer install or update and autoload file should be updated.

Comment: Not working getting same error on command prompt

Comment: Remove the reference to the provider, run composer update on the server and then add it in.

Comment: Actually i am not able to run and composer command on live server

Comment: I can run artisan commands there

Comment: You can download composer from official site and run it via php composer.phar

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to resolve this issue:**

1. Open your laravel project.
2. Goto bootstrap/cache directory
3. delete config.php file

You're done thanks